# NextJS not working on dockerized/nginx app

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, next.js

I am attempting to learn Docker/NGINX and trying to dockerize and deploy my NextJS app. I am able to get to the screen where it shows 'Welcome to nginx!' but that is all. I have tried so many different configurations but have the same result so I feel like I am overlooking something.

'Yarn build' and 'Yarn run dev' both work locally and NextJS appears as it should. Along with my backend and PGSQL both working correctly both in container and locally. Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Folder tree:

```
project  
│
└───frontend
│   │   └───src
│   │       │   components
│   │       │   lib 
│   │       │   pages
│   │              └───_app.tsx
│   |                  _document.tsx
│   |                  404.tsx
│   |                  index.tsx
|   |
|   |
│   │   tsconfig.json
│   │   yarn.lock
│   │   Dockerfile
│   │   nginx.conf  
│   
│
│      
└─docker-compose.ci.yml     
└─docker-compose.override.yml    
└─docker-compose.yml
```

nginx.conf

```
upstream nextjs_upstream {
  server localhost:3000;

}

server {
  listen 80;

  server_name _;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://nextjs_upstream;
  }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest as builder

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

COPY ./ ./

RUN yarn build

RUN yarn install 

FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json next.config.js .env* ./
# COPY --from=builder /usr/app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /usr/app/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node_modules/.bin/next", "start"]
```

docker-compose.ci.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  backend:
    image: 'jrjobfinder-backend:latest'

  frontend:
    image: 'jrjobfinder-frontend:latest'
```

docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  postgres:
    ports:
      - "5430:5430"
    volumes:
      - app-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:cached

  backend:
    command: uvicorn --port 8000 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload main:app
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app:delegated
      - root-home:/root:delegated
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U postgres
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 3

  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    env_file: .env
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy

  frontend:
    build:
      context: frontend
    ports:
      - '3000:80'
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app:delegated
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production

volumes:
  app-db-data:
  root-home:
```

Comment: You need to provide more information, like how you are building images. Which docker-compose file to look for.
In your docker-compose.yml, you have binded 3000 of host to container's 80. But, your container is exposing 3000.

Comment: And, I cant see any usage of nginx.conf